# Using dist() to obtain dendrogram for cluster analysis in R

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I have a data frame on the name data1, looking like this below

```
  pc month1 month2 ...
1  A     12      1
2  B      3      3
3  C      2     56
4  D     13      8
```

pc has 274 rows and there are 85 columns (from pc to month84). My data represent water demand in each postal code (represented by pc-column) of my city of residence. What I want to do is to find clusters where I can group different postal codes with the same demand characteristics over a certain period of time(from month1 to month84). I use the dist() like below, to obtain a dis-similarity matrix, but i keep getting errors.

```
d<-dist(as.matrix(data1),method="euclidean")

Warning message:
In dist(data1, method = "euclidean") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

After that I intend to use something like this, to get the desired dendrogram

```
hc<-hclust(d)
plot(hc)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should remove the non numerical columns (`data1[, -1`)if you intend to compute the distances between individuals.

Comment: @MamounBenghezal thnx for your comment! What you suggested doesn't work though.It keeps giving me the same errors and when i write the last two commands like presented above it shows an error message: **Error in hclust(d) : NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 11)**